# Laravel 5.1 - Checking if the date expired

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

i'm doing an ecommerce, i created:

> -Session "cart" with all products attributes ( price, id, quantity, category etc)
>
> -CouponController.php

```
namespace dixard\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use dixard\Http\Requests;
use dixard\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use dixard\Coupon;
use dixard\Http\Controllers\Carbon\Carbon;

class CouponController extends Controller

public function postCoupon(Request $request)
        {

            $cart = \Session::get('cart');

            $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now(); // today

            // i check if code coupon exist into my DB

            $coupon = Coupon::where('code', $request->get('coupon'))->first();

            if (!empty($coupon) && $coupon->expire_date ) {


                // i need check IF coupon exist AND date not expired --> i will put a new price into my session cart products.  

            }

        }
```

> Model Coupon.php

```
protected $table = 'coupons';

    protected $fillable = [

    'code', // code of coupon
    'price', // price discount
    'expire_date', // expire date of coupon

    ];
```

MY QUESTION

I would like:

1. Check with my CouponController if the code coupon is expired or not
2. If expired return a simply message "Coupon invalid"
3. If Coupon code exist into my DB and NOT expired, i need create a new variable with price value of coupon , for example "$discount = Coupon->price", so i can pass my discount price to my checkout view.

How can i do this ?

Thank you for yout help! ( i read something about carbon, but i dont undestand fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$coupon->expire_date` is not instance of `Carbon` already, make it (`new Carbon($coupon->expire_date)`, then simply compare those two objects as if they were numbers.

For example (assuming that `$coupon->expire_date` is instance of `Carbon`:

```
if ($coupon->expire_date >= $my_time) {
  // ok
} else {
  // error, coupon expired
}
```

Carbon is very handy for all sorts of comparisons, calculating differences etc. [Here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) you can find loads of examples.

Comment: I need install carbon before? i need insert into my composer? or i can insert class carbon without install nothing? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have carbon already, it comes with laravel and you're using it already, just as you've used it for `$mytime` variable

Answer (score 9):

Use [date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) in order to make `expire_date` field a Carbon instance automatically.

```
class Coupon extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['expire_date'];
}
```

So after that I think you only need to check if the expiring date of coupon is a future date.

```
if (!empty($coupon) && $coupon->expire_date->isFuture() ) {
    // valid coupon
}
else{
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['coupon' => 'Coupon is not valid']);
}
```

Comment: i'm trying but i get a error:  InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Data missing

Comment: yes the right class is use Carbon/Carbon; now it work! thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $startDate = Carbon::parse($yourModelObject['created_at'])->format('d.m.Y h:m:sa');
    $endDate = Carbon::parse($yourModelObject['created_at'])->addMinutes(720)->format('d.m.Y h:m:sa');

    if ($now->between($startDate, $endDate)) {
        return 'Date is Active';
    } else {
        return 'Date is Expired';
    }
```